# How to use Git to have different working directory structures on different platforms?

Tags: git

On Windows we have `root\folder1`, `root\folder2`, `root\folder3`.
On Linux we have `root/folder1/folder2`, `root/folder1/folder3`

I would strongly prefer NOT to use submodules nor subtreees.

Is there another solution? Would it work to create a branch and re-arrange the files to the Linux structure? And would merges between the branches make sense?

Edit

I have done much more reading, especially about branch work flows. I'm now re-considering the NOT submodules statement. I was concerned with having the day-to-day developer repository containing submodules and the complications that seems to entail. But, I think that the developers do not need submodules, they can meet the need with embedded repositories.

Say `folder 1`, `folder 2` and `folder3` are separate git repositories - `repo 1`, `repo 2` and `repo 3`. On Windows the 3 repositories are separate. On Linux, `folder 1` is `repo 1`, `folder1/folder 2` is `repo 2`, etc.

If I'm in `folder 1` and there are changes in `folder 2`, will a `git add .` not include the `folder`2 change? Does git stop when it sees another `.git`?

There could be 2 separate bare repositories for building which includes the 3 repos as submodules in the appropriate configuration for Windows and Linux. The release branches can then be managed here. But what branching is seen in `repo 1, 2 and 3`? Has anyone tried something like this? Did it work well?

Comment: On Linux you can create and track symbolic links. But, you are better off refactoring your app to have the same directory structure on all platforms

Comment: I have edited my answer below to address your edit.

Answer (score 3):

Beside the symlinks [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160793/how-to-use-git-to-have-different-working-directory-structures-on-different-platf/17162624#comment24843882_17160793) by [mvp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1734130/mvp) (note: you can have [symlink on Windows 7+ too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link), see also "[Git Symlinks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows)"), this would be a *deployment* issue:

Ie: you would have:

- your regular local clone
- a copy of that clone with the right structure
- a way to diff/import any modification made in that copy back into the regular git repo

... so yes, keeping a common directory structure remains the simplest solution.

---

> If I'm in `folder 1` and there are changes in `folder 2`, will a `git add .` not include the `folder 2` change?

No, it will only consider changers in any part of `folder 1`, *except* `folder 2` content.

> Does git stop when it sees another .git?

Exactly.

> There could be 2 separate bare repositories for building which includes the 3 repos as submodules in the appropriate configuration for Windows and Linux

Note: a bare repo cannot contain another repo, since there is no working tree for said repo to include... anything.

A nested repo wouldn't be recorded at all in a branch of a parent repo, contrary to a submodule.

---

> I suspect subtree is a better fit for us.

Yes, [subtree (part of git since 1.7.11)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12668266/6309) would involve 2 repos: one for Windows and one for Linux.
Each one would aggregate subtree repos with the right structure.

Comment: Pretty sure that git won't add or create symbolic links on any version of Windows...?

Comment: @EdwardThomson git alone won't add/create symlink, yes, you are correct. But a script registered as a post-checkout hook could: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5917249/6309

Comment: Phew, just checking...  symbolic links and junctions are so odd on Windows that I would have been frightened if that functionality had been added (in the box, so to speak) but I wouldn't have been shocked!  :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm a little unclear on the bare repositories. Are you saying that a bare repo cannot contain a submodule given a submodule is a repo?

Comment: @RobG a bare repo can contain the *reference* of a submodule (as a [special entry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2300638/6309)), but since a bare repo doesn't show any actual file (no working tree), you won't see that submodule content. I was referring to nested git repo (not submodules): a bare repo cannot contained a nested repo because a nested repo is not a bare repo (it has a working tree). A bare repo can contain a reference to a submodule. Not a nested repo.

Comment: OK. So, when a branch is created in a repo, say `Parent Repo`, that contains submodules, can that branch be synced to the repo that the submodule represents? That is, can it be seen? Can a developer work on, say, a Release branch in `Repo 1` synced from `Parent Repo`/Release? and push commits back to `Parent Repo`/Release?

Comment: @RobG branches form a parent repo have no relationship whatsoever with branches in a submodule (or with branches in a simple nested git repo, for that matter). You can however configure a submodule to follow a branch from the [upstream repo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) that submodule is from: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17199855/6309. Again, the parent repo doesn't care what branch you are working on in the submodule (and the submodule ignores completely the existence of a parent repo).

Comment: For more on that, see **[true nature of submodules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309)**.

Comment: @VonC What I read on submodules does not make me think its a good technique for us to solve the Windows/Linux difference. It may become necessary if our repo becomes too large for Git to handle well. Then we made need to split it up.

Comment: @VonC I suspect `subtree` is a better fit for us.

Comment: @RobG yes, I have added this option to the answer, with a link to more details about subtrees.