# svn external for git?

Tags: git, svn-externals

New to git, I have searched a lot, didn't find a robust solution.

I got 2 projects, A and B.
A contains `[A code]` and `[SHARED CODE]`, B contains `[B code]` and `[SHARED CODE]`.

With svn, I could put a svn external in project B that links to **subdirectory** of project A, meaning `A->[SHARED CODE]`.

However, it seems git does not allow partial clone, so if I choose submodule, I have to make it 3 projects: `SHARED CODE`, `A` and `B`, that is painful.

Worse is, when I make some change in `A->[SHARED CODE]`(which is a submodule), it seems quite hard to commit and push it, and a `git pull` operation on `B` does not automatically pull the latest code to `B->[SHARED CODE]`.

So any convenient solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: seems http://blog.quilitz.de/2010/03/checkout-sub-directories-in-git-sparse-checkouts/comment-page-1/ is a solution, didn't figure out yet, but working on it.

Answer (score 2):

Yet, submodule remains the right solution, especially since git1.8.2:

See "[Git submodule new version update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17199855/6309)"

A submodule can be configured to follow the latest of a branch, so this would be enough to update all your submodules to the latest commit:

```
 git submodule update --remote
```

Yes, that means 3 repos, but that is consistent with the role a git repo is supposed to play: it represents a "component", that is a coherent group of file with its own independent history.

Comment: @user2530437 as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/6309, I presume? Seems nice.

Comment: @user2530437 be careful: That is not the git way and might cause you problems in the future. Git is not svn and will resist if you try to make it so ;).