# how to update one submodule git?

Tags: git, github

I have a couple of submodules and I only want to update one of them.

I think this command updates all of them in `.gitmodules`

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
```

I just want one of the modules updated though.

Comment: Do you want to update a submodule to the latest commit?  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828324/update-git-submodule-to-latest-commit-on-origin

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`git submodule update` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--ltpathgt82308203) takes a path as a parameter.

Use the path of the submodule you want to update, as said path is recorded in your `.gitmodules`.

```
git submodule update --init --remote a/submodule/path
```

Make sure:

- you execute the command where your `.gitmodule` is.
- [your submodule follows a branch first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17199855/6309).

For a manual update, you also can go into the submodule folder, and do a  `git checkout aBranch/git pull` yourself. Then go back to the parent repo, add and commit the new gitlink SHA1 for that submodule.

Comment: "error: pathspec 'a/submodule/path' did not match any file(s) known to git". This answer misses an important detail: this command must be run in the directory where `.gitmodules` lives, not where the submodules themselves are located.

Comment: @MSalters Thank you for the feedback, good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.